# UFW blocks all traffic after enabled

Tags: firewall, ufw, mail-server

I have Ubuntu 16.04 mail server. Suddenly `ufw` block all traffic (incoming and outgoing). I have not changed any config files.

What can I do now? When I turn on `ufw`, all traffic is blocked.

Answer (score 3):

After enabling [ufw](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW) you need to explicitly enable incoming traffic or whatever. For example,
To allow incoming traffic via [port 25 TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol), use:

```
sudo ufw allow 25/tcp
```

To see the current status, use:

```
sudo ufw status verbose
```

---

For more info: [UFW - Basic Syntax and Examples](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW#Basic_Syntax_and_Examples)

I recommend using [Gufw](http://gufw.org/) which provides a user interface.

Comment: Probably `sudo ufw status verbose` would be more helpful.

Comment: I have already define all rules..

Comment: Moreover, also outgoing traffic like ICMP or tcp ( defeault is allow)